# Absolute continuity of $F=\int_{[0,x]\times [0,x]} f$.

Tags: real-analysis

For $f\in L^1([0,1]\times [0,1])$ with the Lebesgue measure, define $F(x)=\int_{[0,x]\times[0,x]}f$. How can I prove $F$ is absolutely continuous, and express $F'$ with respect to $f$? I can't figure out.

Comment: Fubini's theorem comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that 
$$\sum_i |F(y_i)-F(x_i)|\leq \sum_i\int_{[x_i,y_i]\times[x_i,y_i]\cup[0,x_i]\times[x_i,y_i]\cup[x_i,y_i]\times[0,y_i]}f\\\leq||f||\sum_i(|y_i-x_i|^2+2|y_i-x_i|)\leq3||f||\sum_i|y_i-x_i|$$

Now choose $\delta =\frac{\epsilon}{3||f||}$ in the definition of absolute continuity.

---

We have that $F(x)=\int_{[0,x]\times[0,x]}f$. Then $F(x)=G(x,x)$ where $G(x,y)=\int_{[0,x]\times[0,y]}f$.

We apply chain rule.

$$F'(x)=G_1(x,x)+G_2(x,x)=\int_{[0,x]}f(x,t)dt+\int_{[0,x]}f(t,x)dt$$

Answer (score 0):

Put
$$\Phi(x,y) = \int_0^x \int_0^y f(s,t)\,dt\,ds.$$
Then
$$\partial_x\Phi(x,y) = \int_0^y f(x,t)\,dt$$
and
$$\partial_y\Phi(x,y) = \int_0^x f(t,x)\,dt$$
Invoke the chain rule to get
$$F'(x) = \partial_x\Phi(x,x) + \partial_y\Phi(x,x) = \int_0^x f(x,t) + f(t,x)\,dt$$